# How to backup protected apps for later use?

Tags: backup, apk, protected-apps

I there any way i can backup the protected apps as apks as it is possible to backup free apps using the avilable backups apps for later use.

why i want this: I don't want to download the apps again to save bandwidth as i have other devices too(with same email).

Comment: No chance without root I'm afraid. This was one feature ThinkAndroid wanted to put into AppMonsterPro, and they finally had to use SUPERUSER permission for that. So I doubt it's (currently) possible without root.